# What is a parallel vector space and how do I show it is isomorphic to the solution space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

How can I create an isomorphism between the solution space and a parallel vector space. I'm not sure how to define the vector space and the isomorphism.

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 & 4 \\
        4 & -8\\
        \end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}
        x  \\
        y  \\
        \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
        -8  \\
        16  \\
        \end{bmatrix}  $$

Comment: what do you mean by "parallel vector space"?

Comment: I believe it refers to a parallel vector of [x;y]. I need to find an isomorphism between W and parallel vector space V

Comment: @AllenMiller So you do not know the definition of parallel vector space?  I have added the definition tag and modified your title.

Comment: Can you help explain how I can make this isomorphism? Can you describe a parallel vector space?

Answer (score 1):

The solution space is the line $y=x/2-2$. Since it does not pass through the origin $(0,0)$, it is not a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^2$. Rather, it is an affine subspace, which by definition is a set of the form $V+u$ where $V$ is a vector subspace and $u$ is a fixed vector. This $V$ is the parallel vector space that you are looking for. The map $x\mapsto x+u$ is a desired isomorphism. The space $V$ is unique for a given affine subspace, but $u$ generally is not.

Since we are talking about lines on a plane, things are not very complicated. Two lines are parallel if they have the slope. So, $y=x/2$ is the parallel vector space. An example of isomorphism between them is $(x,x/2)\mapsto (x,x/2-2)$.

In general, the solution space of the system $Ax=b$ has parallel vector space described by the system $Ax=0$.